# Uninitialised values in dynamic array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memory-management, valgrind

I've been given a task that requires a dynamic 2D array in C, but we haven't even covered pointers yet, so I'm kind of at a loss here. I have to read some text input and store it in a 2D array, without limiting its size.
Unfortunately, Valgrind keeps throwing me an error saying that there's an uninitialised value, when the puts() function executes and sometimes it prints out some random signs. I understand that I must have omitted some indexes, but I just can't find where the issue stems from. Additionally, all advices regarding the quality of my code are very much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>


#define MULT 3
#define DIV 2


char **read(int *row, int *col) {
    char **input = NULL;
    int row_size = 0;
    int col_size = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != '\n') { // skip empty lines

            assert(i < INT_MAX);
            if (i == row_size) { // if not enough row memory, allocate more
                row_size = 1 + row_size * MULT / DIV;
                input = realloc(input, row_size * sizeof *input);
                assert(input != NULL);
            }

            char *line = NULL;
            int j = 0;
            // I need all the rows to be of the same size (see last loop)
            line = malloc(col_size * sizeof *line); 

            // do while, so as to not skip the first character
            do { 
                assert(j < INT_MAX-1);
                if (j == col_size) {
                    col_size = 1 + col_size * MULT / DIV;
                    line = realloc(line, col_size * sizeof *line);
                    assert(line != NULL);
                }
                line[j++] = c;
            } while(((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF));

            // zero-terminate the string
            if (j == col_size) {
                ++col_size;
                line = realloc(line, col_size * sizeof *line);
                line[j] = '\0';
            }

            input[i++] = line;
        }
    }
    // Here I give all the lines the same length
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        input[j] = realloc(input[j], col_size * sizeof *(input+j));

    *row = i;
    *col = col_size;
    return input;
}


int main(void) {
    int row_size, col_size, i, j;
    char **board = read(&row_size, &col_size);

    // Initialize the remaining elements of each array
    for (i = 0; i < row_size; ++i) {
        j = 0;
        while (board[i][j] != '\0')
            ++j;
        while (j < col_size-1)
            board[i][++j] = ' ';
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row_size; ++i) {
        puts(board[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row_size; ++i)
        free(board[i]);
    free(board);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the null-terminator only if `j == col_size`? I think you need to set it always.

Comment: Hmm maybe, I just adapted the example code given by our teacher for a regular array.

Comment: It would be fine if you weren't relying on the strings being null-terminated (e.g. in `puts`) and actually in your `main` you expect all additional chars after the strings to be `\0`, so you need to zero-initialize all of the additionally allocated column memory.

Comment: No, I set only one `\0` in each column and I turn all the other elements into `' '` in the main function.

Comment: Ah right, the previous point still stands though. Without `\0` somewhere you are leaving the over-allocated space uninitialized even in `main`.

Comment: I don't think I understand, sadly. Why is `\0` not being placed?

Comment: If you realloc for `col_size` more than one additional character, but then read only one more character, `j == col_size` will be false when the row is read, and you will never place a `\0` in the row. In `main` you then don't change the row because of `while (board[i][j] != '\0') ++j;` and so the additional space from the `realloc` of the row is uninialized.

Comment: Oh my god, I feel so stupid now, the `\0` was supposed to be added after the `if`.  Thanks ;D

Comment: @eukaryota good catch, feel free to add that as an answer, so OP can accept it.

Comment: @eukaryota oh btw, since I don't want to post another question. Would it be possible to put the assert/realloc part into a function? The problem I'm encountering is that I have to give it type char** as an argument first and then char*.

Comment: @guben You can always pass a pair of `void*` together with the type's size. Whether this is a good design choice you better ask in another question.